# Path to testsuite file in robot Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I'm trying to get the path of test files given to pybot via the command line in the python code:

I tried:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

file_path = BuiltIn().run_keyword("Get Variable Value", "${CURDIR}")
```

It returns `none`, any guess?

Comment: Are you doing this inside a custom keyword? Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable that stores it is `${SUITE SOURCE}`.
Also, it's not needed to go through the `run_keyword()`, you can just call `get_variable_value` directly:

```
file_path = BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${SUITE SOURCE}")
```

Keep in mind the returned value is an absolute path.